# How do I use HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE to change the language on my Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, lang

I'm trying to change the language of my Laravel app when the user goes to any of its urls it has "/", "faq", "user/1/edit", I know I can use the request to find out about the server accepted language:

```
$locale = request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE');
```

And I'm already working on my resources/lang files.

Question is: If the user got a direct link to one of the pages and he is loading it, how do I change the language no matter what route they are going to and show the page in his language?

Answer (score 2):

Create a Middleware assigned to all routes that should be translated and use the App::setLocale() with the correct value (I believe you want to get it from the browser's Accept-Language header)

Comment: That's one of my initials thoughts, let's see if there are some other ideas here